# How do you prefer to switch between buffers in Vim?

Tags: vim, editor, buffer

I've tried [MiniBufExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159), but I usually end up with several windows showing it or close it altogether. What I'd like is something like [LustyJuggler](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2050) with incremental search, the way I switch between buffers in Emacs. Surely there is a script like this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have been using Wincent Colaiuta's [Command-T vim plugin](https://wincent.com/products/command-t/) for a couple months now. Wincent wrote the parts of it that need to be fast in C, and I must say that it is! And, I think its file pattern matching logic is even better than Textmate's Command-T. Check out the [screencast](https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.wincent.com/command-t/screencasts/command-t-demo.mov?width=640&height=480).

> The Command-T plug-in for VIM provides
>   an extremely fast, intuitive mechanism
>   for opening files with a minimal
>   number of keystrokes. It's named
>   "Command-T" because it is inspired by
>   the "Go to File" window bound to
>   Command-T in TextMate.
>
> Files are selected by typing
>   characters that appear in their paths,
>   and are ordered by an algorithm which
>   knows that characters that appear in
>   certain locations (for example,
>   immediately after a path separator)
>   should be given more weight.

[Easier buffer switching](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching) contains many useful tips. I have adapted the following to my .vimrc, which does buffer-name auto-completion, maps the most useful buffer-switching commands to my <Leader> and left-side home row keys, and shows the current buffer number in the status line:

```
"" Tab triggers buffer-name auto-completion
set wildchar=<Tab> wildmenu wildmode=full

let mapleader = ","

map <Leader>t :CommandT<Return>
map <Leader>a :bprev<Return>
map <Leader>s :bnext<Return>
map <Leader>d :bd<Return>
map <Leader>f :b 

"" Show the buffer number in the status line.
set laststatus=2 statusline=%02n:%<%f\ %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
```

I also use [MiniBufExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159), which provides a compact listing of each listed buffer in its own horizontal split up top.

Answer (score 79):

I used to use a combination of tabs and multiple `gvim` instances, keeping groups of related files as tabs in each instance.  So long as I didn't end up with too many tabs in one instance, the tab bar shows you the name of each file you're editing at a glance.

Then I read a post by Jamis Buck on how he switched [from TextMate back to vim](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2008/10/10/coming-home-to-vim), and learned some great tricks:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> to split the current window
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> to switch back and forth between two buffers in the same window.
- the awesome [fuzzyfinder.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) which gives you auto-completing search of files in your current directory or of buffers you currently have open
- Jamis' own [fuzzy_file_finder](http://github.com/jamis/fuzzy_file_finder/tree/master) and [fuzzyfinder_textmate](http://github.com/jamis/fuzzyfinder_textmate/tree/master), which slightly modify how `fuzzyfinder` works to behave more like a similar feature in `TextMate` (as far as I can tell, the difference is that it matches anywhere in the filename instead of only from the start).  Watch [this video](http://s3.amazonaws.com/buckblog/videos/fuzzyfinder_textmate.mov) to see it in action.

Now I just have one `gvim` instance, maximised, and split it into multiple windows so I can see several files at once.  I bound <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to `fuzzyfinder\_textmate`, so now if I type (say) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> `mod/usob` it opens up `app/models/user\_observer.rb`.  I almost never bother with tabs any more.

**Update 2010/08/07**

While `fuzzyfinder\_textmate` remains awesome, as Casey points out in the comments, it's no longer maintained.  Also, it (and/or `fuzzyfinder.vim`) gets a bit slow and unstable when working with large projects (lots of directories or files), so I've been looking for an alternative.

Fortunately, there seems to be a very nice alternative in the form of [Wincent Colaiuta](http://wincent.com)'s [Command-T plugin](https://wincent.com/products/command-t/).  This has very similar (if not slightly better) behaviour to `fuzzyfinder\_textmate`, but is noticeably faster; it also has nice features like being able to open the found file in a split or vertical split.  Thanks (and upvotes!) to David Rivers for pointing to it.

Comment: Yes, fuzzyfinder is a very close fit to what I want.

Comment: Jamis' fuzzyfinder_textmate completes vim.  It should really become a core feature!

Comment: It looks like Jami has stop working on this project. Maybe the original author will pull in these features?

http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2009/1/28/the-future-of-fuzzyfinder-textmate

Comment: Sam, thanks for the props that you gave me (on my birthday!) :D

Comment: Try the ctrlp vim plugin (http://kien.github.com/ctrlp.vim/) it implement fuzzyfinder but with a ton more useful features :)

Comment: Unite is great along with Ycm and keeping file tags in your source is good too. try ":Unite buffer" or ":Unite file" - Dislexics Untie!

Answer (score 34):

I use the basics -  '`:ls`' + '`:bn`'/'`:bp`' + '`:b <part-of-name>`'

Comment: :-) I never thought I'd see "simple" and "':ls' + ':bn'/':bp' + ':b <part-of-name>'" in the same sentence.

Comment: Pax, I still don't see it. :-)

Comment: This, plus `:map <c-n> :bn<cr>` and `:map <c-p> :bp<cr>`, since `C-n` and `C-p` are fast to type and allow cycling between buffers if you press them repeatedly. (I never used them for their original purpose.) It's like cycling between browser tabs with `C-PgUp` and `C-PgDn` or whatever shortcut your browser has.

Comment: Ctrl+N is the standard for 'New File' in the majority of other editors and Ctrl+P is the paste command, so for most people these will be really confusing. Tim Pope's [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) gives you `[b` for the previous buffer and `]b` for the next buffer. Plus loads of other goodies that use the concept of `]` for next and `[` for previous.

Answer (score 33):

I like "ctrl-w s" and "ctlr-w v" to split the window. Then I map the movement keys (h, j, k, l) with ctrl held down to move between the split windows:

```
" Map ctrl-movement keys to window switching
map <C-k> <C-w><Up>
map <C-j> <C-w><Down>
map <C-l> <C-w><Right>
map <C-h> <C-w><Left>
```

Having to move my hand over to the arrow keys is annoying.

Next, I set up ctlr-tab to switch between buffers in the current window (like a lot of other environments):

```
" Switch to alternate file
map <C-Tab> :bnext<cr>
map <C-S-Tab> :bprevious<cr>
```

These have worked pretty well for me over the last several years although vim always has more secrets than you can know.

Comment: Your comment "switch to alternate file" is misleading because Vim has an alternate file already, it's the previous file you were on, and you can switch the current (%) and alternate (#) files easily using ctrl-6.

Comment: Also, <C-w> with hjkl will switch windows--arrow keys not required.

Comment: <C-S-Tab> is asking for RSI. I have mapped <S-J> to `:bp` and <S-K> to `:bn`

Comment: Remapping <S-J> seems like a poor choice in normal mode, as that is commonly used (for concatenating lines).

Answer (score 18):

```
nmap <Leader>bb :ls<CR>:buffer<Space>
```

and nobody mentioned nice plugin [ctrlp.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736). Using this plugin you can search buffer by name.

Comment: I like that mapping! Smart and flexible.

Answer (score 15):

I use

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> for next buffer

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> for previous buffer

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> for next tab

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> for previous tab

Here is the `.vimrc` configuration:

```
map <C-J> :bnext<CR>
map <C-K> :bprev<CR>
map <C-L> :tabn<CR>
map <C-H> :tabp<CR>
```

See http://syskall.com/my-biggest-vim-productivity-boost/

Answer (score 6):

```
imap <A-1> <Esc>:tabn 1<CR>i
imap <A-2> <Esc>:tabn 2<CR>i
imap <A-3> <Esc>:tabn 3<CR>i
imap <A-4> <Esc>:tabn 4<CR>i
imap <A-5> <Esc>:tabn 5<CR>i
imap <A-6> <Esc>:tabn 6<CR>i
imap <A-7> <Esc>:tabn 7<CR>i
imap <A-8> <Esc>:tabn 8<CR>i
imap <A-9> <Esc>:tabn 9<CR>i

map <A-1> :tabn 1<CR>
map <A-2> :tabn 2<CR>
map <A-3> :tabn 3<CR>
map <A-4> :tabn 4<CR>
map <A-5> :tabn 5<CR>
map <A-6> :tabn 6<CR>
map <A-7> :tabn 7<CR>
map <A-8> :tabn 8<CR>
map <A-9> :tabn 9<CR>
```

Comment: The most interesting thing with Vim is that you may learn something every day !

Comment: The question is about *buffers*, not *tabs*... but you can `:tab sball` first, or instead of using `:tabn` you should use `:buffer`

Comment: Yes! This was what I was looking for, whether anyone was using the Alt-<num> mappings or if those had hidden traps (like the Ctrl-<num> ones do). I'm planning to also make use of the second code sample from https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching#Mappings_for_buffer_number (basically, use a `while` loop and `execute`) to make this more concise and easier to work with.

Answer (score 6):

I've recently gone more minimalistic.

To cycle buffers I use <kbd>]b</kbd> and <kbd>[b</kbd> from unimpaired: https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired

To jump straight to an open buffer just use Vim's tab completion with <kbd>:b</kbd>. A few letters is enough to get to any open buffer with a tab or two.

Similarly to open buffers I use <kbd>:e</kbd> with relative paths and tab complete.

I also use <kbd>:ls</kbd> occasionally to see what buffers I have open (and to check their modified status).

To get rid of a buffer I use <kbd>:bw</kbd> to wipe the buffer. I usually make a temporary split and change buffers to preserve my layout though since <kbd>:bw</kbd> also closes the active window.

All the minibuf things I tried just ended up annoying me, and I don't want some smart-matching thing opening random files for me. If I really need to browse for something I use NERDtree (<kbd>:e .</kbd>).

IDK, Lately I also dropped Yankring (because it screws up <kbd>xp</kbd>) and started using registers, and I recently decided the <kbd>f</kbd>/<kbd>t</kbd> movements are the greatest thing ever...

Comment: This is all great advice. I mapped `<leader>ll` to `:ls`. Also it's really useful to make sure that you have `set wildmenu` in your `.vimrc` as then you get a small menu that comes up with all the alternatives for `:b`

Answer (score 4):

To list and switch between buffers I use:

```
nnoremap <Leader>l :ls<CR>:b<space>
```

To switch between buffers:

```
map <Leader>n :bn<CR>
map <Leader>p :bp<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

The excellent [Buffer Explorer](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=42), the be has gotten to be such strong muscle memory that I find myself wishing I could use it in other applications.  I find it to be extremely fast when actively editing more than two files.

Answer (score 2):

I've spent quite a while building my .vimrc to work with this HTML::Mason project I've been on for four years, so I have an odd mix of tabs and split windows.  For your viewing enjoyment:

```
map ;o :Sex <CR>
map <C-J> <C-W>j
map <C-K> <C-W>k
map <C-l> <C-W>l
map <C-h> <C-W>h
map ;] :tabnext<CR>
map ;[ :tabprev<CR>
map <C-t> :tabe +"browse ."<CR>
map <C-O> :NERDTreeToggle ~/curr/trunk/<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [tselectbuffer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1866). It's really fast and unlike bufexplorer doesn't take space in your window. It also has a incremental search.I tried minibufexplorer and I found the navigation in the buffer a bit difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, now I use both. The defaults for BufExplorer are `,be`, `,bs`, `,bv`, so I mapped TSelectBuffer to `,bb`.

Answer (score 2):

I have mapped `<S-J>` and `<S-K>` to `:bp` and `:bn`, although I admit I don't use it as the number of files is greater than 10. I have then mapped `<C-J>` and `<C-K>` to Gnome Terminal's previous and next tabs, and I usually run 4 instances of vim for each of the 4 different projects I work on. I still really wish next and previous buffer would go to the history of buffers I have been working on, and not the order int he buffer list.

Answer (score 2):

I use tselectbuffer. It's really fast and unlike bufexplorer doesn't take space in your window. It also has a incremental search.I tried minibufexplorer and I found the navigation in the buffer a bit difficult.

Answer (score 0):

i use simple :vsplit with ^W+w/^W+r and :tabnew with Ctrl+Alt+PgUp/PgDown key combinations.

Comment: I have to agree with what [Zathrus](http://stackoverflow.com/users/16220/zathrus) said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102384/using-vims-tabs-like-buffers#103590). Tabs in Vim (or Emacs with TabBar for that matter) simply do not work like in the usual tabbed interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

When there are several buffers open in a Vim session, it can become difficult to keep track of the buffers and their respective buffer numbers. If this is the case, switching to a different file can be made easier using a simple map:

> :nnoremap (F5) :buffers(CR):buffer(Space)

[vim.wikia.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching)