# How do I navigate buffers in vim?

Tags: vim

I normally work with more than 5 files at a time. I use buffers to open different files.
I use commands such as :buf file1, :buf file2 etc.
Is there a faster way to move to different files?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What I use:

- Go to the previous buffer: `:b#` or `:bp`
- Go to the next buffer: `:bn`
- If you know your file is loaded in buffer 5: `:b5`
- To get a list of buffers: `:buffers` or shorter: `:ls`

And have a short look on [`:he buffer`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:buffer)

And the wiki entry on Easier Buffer Switching on the Vim Wiki: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching

SO already has a question regarding yours: [How do you prefer to switch between buffers in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327411/how-do-you-prefer-to-switch-between-buffers-in-vim)

Answer (score 9):

A few mappings can make your life a lot easier.

This one lists your buffers and prompts you for a number:

```
nnoremap gb :buffers<CR>:buffer<Space>
```

[image: gb]

This one lists your buffers in the "wildmenu". Depends on the `'wildcharm'` option as well as `'wildmenu'` and `'wildmode'`:

```
nnoremap <leader>b :buffer <C-z>
```

[image: <leader>b]

These ones allow you to cycle between all your buffers without much thinking:

```
nnoremap <PageUp>   :bprevious<CR>
nnoremap <PageDown> :bnext<CR>
```

Also, don't forget `<C-^>` which allows you to alternate between two buffers.

Answer (score 4):

Below I describe some excerpts from sections of my `.vimrc`. It includes mapping the leader key, setting wilds tab completion, and finally my buffer nav key choices (all mostly inspired by folks on the interweb, including romainl). Edit: Then I ramble on about my shortcuts for windows and tabs.

```
" easier default keys {{{1

let mapleader=','
nnoremap <leader>2 :@"<CR>
```

The `leader` key is a prefix key for mostly user-defined key commands (some plugins also use it). The default is `\`, but many people suggest the easier to reach `,`.

The second line there is a command to `@` execute from the `"` clipboard, in case you'd like to quickly try out various key bindings (without relying on `:so %`). (My nmeumonic is that <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd> is <kbd>@</kbd>.)

```
" wilds {{{1

set wildmenu wildmode=list:full
set wildcharm=<C-z>
set wildignore+=*~ wildignorecase
```

For built-in completion, `wildmenu` is probably the part that shows up yellow on your Vim when using tab completion on command-line. `wildmode` is set to a comma-separated list, each coming up in turn on each tab completion (that is, my list is simply one element, `list:full`). `list` shows rows and columns of candidates. `full`'s meaning includes maintaining existence of the `wildmenu`. `wildcharm` is the way to include <kbd>Tab</kbd> presses in your macros. The `*~` is for my use in `:edit` and `:find` commands.

```
" nav keys {{{1
" windows, buffers and tabs {{{2
" buffers {{{3

nnoremap <leader>bb :b <C-z><S-Tab>
nnoremap <leader>bh :ls!<CR>:b<Space>
nnoremap <leader>bw :ls!<CR>:bw<Space>
nnoremap <leader>bt :TSelectBuffer<CR>
nnoremap <leader>be :BufExplorer<CR>
nnoremap <leader>bs :BufExplorerHorizontalSplit<CR>
nnoremap <leader>bv :BufExplorerVerticalSplit<CR>
nnoremap <leader>3 :e#<CR>
nmap <C-n> :bn<cr>
nmap <C-p> :bp<cr>
```

The `,3` is for switching between the "two" last buffers (Easier to reach than built-in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd>). Nmeuonic is <kbd>Shift</kbd>- <kbd>3</kbd> is <kbd>#</kbd>, and `#` is the register symbol for last buffer. (See `:marks`.)

`,bh` is to select from hidden buffers (`!`).

`,bw` is to `bwipeout` buffers by number or name. For instance, you can wipeout several while looking at the list, with `,bw 1 3 4 8 10 <CR>`. Note that wipeout is more destructive than `:bdelete`. They have their pros and cons. For instance, `:bdelete` leaves the buffer in the hidden list, while `:bwipeout` removes global marks (see `:help marks`, and the description of uppercase marks).

I haven't settled on these keybindings, I would sort of prefer that my `,bb` was simply `,b` (simply defining while leaving the others defined makes Vim pause to see if you'll enter more).

Those shortcuts for `:BufExplorer` are actually the defaults for that plugin, but I have it written out so I can change them if I want to start using `,b` without a hang.

## You didn't ask for this:

If you still find Vim buffers a little awkward to use, try to combine the functionality with tabs and windows (until you get more comfortable?).

```
" windows {{{3

" window nav
nnoremap <leader>w <C-w>
nnoremap <M-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <M-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <M-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <M-l> <C-w>l
" resize window
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w><
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>+
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>-
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>>
```

Notice how nice `,w` is for a prefix. Also, I reserve `Ctrl` key for resizing, because `Alt` (`M-`) is hard to realize in all environments, and I don't have a better way to resize. I'm fine using `,w` to switch windows.

```
" tabs {{{3

nnoremap <leader>t :tab
nnoremap <M-n> :tabn<cr>
nnoremap <M-p> :tabp<cr>
nnoremap <C-Tab> :tabn<cr>
nnoremap <C-S-Tab> :tabp<cr>
nnoremap tn :tabe<CR>
nnoremap te :tabe<Space><C-z><S-Tab>
nnoremap tf :tabf<Space>
nnoremap tc :tabc<CR>
nnoremap to :tabo<CR>
nnoremap tm :tabm<CR>
nnoremap ts :tabs<CR>

nnoremap th :tabr<CR>
nnoremap tj :tabn<CR>
nnoremap tk :tabp<CR>
nnoremap tl :tabl<CR>

" or, it may make more sense to use
" nnoremap th :tabp<CR>
" nnoremap tj :tabl<CR>
" nnoremap tk :tabr<CR>
" nnoremap tl :tabn<CR>
```

In summary of my window and tabs keys, I can navigate both of them with <kbd>Alt</kbd>, which is actually pretty easy to reach. In other words:

```
" (modifier) key choice explanation {{{3
"
"       KEYS        CTRL                  ALT            
"       hjkl        resize windows        switch windows        
"       np          switch buffer         switch tab      
"
" (resize windows is hard to do otherwise, so we use ctrl which works across
" more environments. i can use ',w' for windowcmds o.w.. alt is comfortable
" enough for fast and gui nav in tabs and windows. we use np for navs that 
" are more linear, hjkl for navs that are more planar.) 
"
```

This way, if the <kbd>Alt</kbd> is working, you can actually hold it down while you find your "open" buffer pretty quickly, amongst the tabs and windows.

Answer (score 1):

Once the buffers are already open, you can just type `:b partial_filename` to switch

So if `:ls` shows that i have my `~./vimrc` open, then I can just type `:b vimr` or `:b rc` to switch to that buffer

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve. The best is the best that WORKS for YOU. You have lots of fuzzy match plugins that help you navigate. The 2 things that impress me most are

1) CtrlP or Unite's fuzzy buffer search

2) LustyExplorer and/or LustyJuggler

And the simplest :

```
:map <F5> :ls<CR>:e #
```

Pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> lists all buffer, just type number.