# old vi command for previous file

Tags: vi

Using vim there are [multiple answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327411/how-do-you-prefer-to-switch-between-buffers-in-vim) to get to previous and next buffers/files. On an older machine we have an older vi. The old `:version` command says 3.10. `:next` works to get to the next buffer. How do I get to a previous file?

Comment: Have you tried `:bprevious`?

Comment: In vim `:prev` worked great but not in vi 3.10. My fingers have been vim trained. The buffer commands didn't work at all with this old version of vi.

Comment: Do you get any help with `:help previous`.

Comment: vi 3.10 for `:help` shows `ex: 0602-025 help is not a recognized command.` I'll look at the vim help on another machine.

Comment: Oh boy. hey there's a [stackexchange site](http://vi.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to  Vim an Vi. You might find some vi whisperers over there.

Comment: good suggestion, thanks @dan08

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found it. I felt a little embarrassed and frustrated as this is a relatively simple thing to do. Along the way I found these excellent vi command references from [washington.edu](http://staff.washington.edu/rells/R110/#tips2), [jeffw.com](http://www.jeffw.com/vi/) and O'Reilly author [kostis.net](http://www.kostis.net/hints/vi-editor.htm#5) that included the old command I needed:

```
:rewind
```