# Vim: can global marks switch tabs instead of the file in the current tab?

Tags: vim, tabs

I'm in the process of learning vim, and i just learned about marks. Before this i found it useful to have all the source code files i'm working on in their own tabs. When i found out about "global" (capital letter) marks i thought it would be a great way to switch to a tab which already has the marked file open, and scroll to the correct spot in a quick way. 
However, i found out that jumping to a mark in a different file simply changes the file which the current tab is displaying, and this messes up my tabs setup.
Is there a way to make the marks work with the tabs in the way that i want?

Comment: Seems like it's not supposed to work like this. I might as well just use buffers i guess.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102384/using-vims-tabs-like-buffers) question and answer, hopefully they will make this question go away :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the mark-jumping commands are designed to move to the mark *within the current window* as there can theoretically be many windows to the same file. You need to switch to a new window *first* using `:sbuf` or `:tabnext` or <kbd>CTRL+W</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>. If you have set `switchbuf=useopen,usetab` then using `:sbuf <otherfile>` first will be sufficient to jump to the other tab where your file is open. But <kbd>'A</kbd> will not create a new window for you (or re-use an existing one in another tab).

You can probably create a mapping for `'` and `` ` `` which uses `getpos()`, `setpos()`, `:sbuf` and `switchbuf` to jump to an existing window in another tab, but it would involve writing a page of vimscript.

See `:help switchbuf` and `:help getpos()` and `:help setpos()`.

Answer (score 1):

Tabs may not be the best way to do what you are trying to do.  When a file is open, it isn't necessarily open in just one tab.  It's open in a buffer, which is a concept not tied to a tab.

In fact, you can have the same buffer open in multiple tabs (or even multiple panes within the same tab).  A tab is more like a window into one or more of your currently open buffers.

It may be better to learn about how to switch between buffers in your current tab or pane.  Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
    nno \ <Cmd>call To_global_mark()<cr>
    fun! To_global_mark()
       -tab drop /tmp/useless.md
        exe 'normal! `' .. toupper(input("To global mark: "))
    endf
```