# more intelligent global bookmarks in vim

Tags: vim

Here's how global bookmarks work.

Let's say I have two tabs in my vim session.  One showing foo.txt, one showing bar.txt.  I go to line 10 in foo.txt and hit **mA**

Then I go to the other tab, showing bar.txt.  I hit **`A**, and the workspace on that tab opens foo.txt, putting my cursor on line 10.

So now I have two tabs, both showing foo.txt.  This is less than ideal.

How I want it to work is, if one of my active workspaces on any tab is showing the file I the bookmark system is trying to navigate too, move my focus to that tab.  If the file isn't open, sure - open it in my active workspace.

Is there any way to make this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: NB: this is not off-topic, please do read the FAQ. However, this is an exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603745/how-do-i-jump-to-markers-within-different-tabs-in-vim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem with Vim's global bookmarks. It's a problem with Vim's tabs.

In most text editors, tabs serve as a *list of currently open files*, but in Vim, the buffer list serves this purpose. If you think of a tab in Vim as being like a saved layout for split windows, then you'll meet less friction. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102384/using-vims-tabs-like-buffers/103590#103590) sums it up nicely, and I made a [screencast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-tabs/) to try and explain how tabs can be used.

Comment: Thanks - I'll have to change how I think of tabs a bit to work with this.  The clarification was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that answers your initial question. But as far as I'm concerned, nelstrom is right: tabs are not meant to contains the others files, but other layouts.

[How do I jump to markers within different tabs in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603745/how-do-i-jump-to-markers-within-different-tabs-in-vim/4604556#4604556)