# vim (gvim) - dock the tab bar on the right instead fo the top

Tags: vim, ubuntu

Is it possible to set the dock position of the tab bar?  I can only see a few tabs in it's default position on top, it would serve me much better on the right.

Is it possible to do this?  Or is there a plugin for keeping the buffers displayed similar to tabs (but docked on the right instead of the top)?  NERDtree is really cool but it doesn't list the open buffer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645440/vim-is-vertical-tab-list-possible

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to put the tab bar on the right. Or anywhere else for that matter, apart from where it is now.

As far as buffers list, there are several plugins for *managing* buffers, [MiniBufExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159) being one of the more popular ones. NERDTree is not really a buffer manager, more of a file manager.