# Tab order in Vim minibufexplorer

Tags: vim, minibufexplorer

Is there any way to change the tab order in Vim minibufexplorer? Or when I opened them once, do they have to stay that way until I will close Vim?

Comment: edited title to reflect what you're asking

Answer (score 2):

Vim always assign the next sequential number for a new buffer. minibufexplorer shows the buffers in [this sequential order](http://www.wavell.net/vim/vim_screenshot.gif). Since you [can't reassign new buffer numbers](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ), you have three options:

- Ask fholgado to implement this feature (he has a [minibufexplorer fork](http://fholgado.com/minibufexpl), and added a lot of good stuff);
- Find another buffer listing plugin that have different sort mechanisms that you like;
- Use tabs instead of buffers, one tab per buffer ([understand the caveats of this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102384/using-vims-tabs-like-buffers)). Using gVim, you can move them as you like, using [some shortcuts](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_tab_pages#Shortcuts).