# Vim: Tabe multiple files?

Tags: vim, tabs

I know about running

```
vim -p file1 file2 file3
```

But is there away to do something similar from within vim?
What I've thought about wanting to do is

```
:tabe file1 file2 file3
```

or (IMO worse, but still an improvement):

```
:edit file1 file2 file3
```

...but neither of those are possible, by default at least.

Comment: This is similar to the following post: Using Vim's tabs like buffers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102384/using-vims-tabs-like-buffers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this:

```
:args file1 file2 file3 |tab sall
```

this will only put newly opened file (`file1, file2, file3`) in tabs, not all buffers.

if you want to open all buffers in tabs, replace `sall` to `sball`

btw, is tab convenient to work with? personally I like working with buffer more...

Comment: I agree. I prefer working with buffers as well. For more information why to use buffers for tabs take a look at this vimcasts by Drew Neil: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-tabs/

Comment: Thanks! That's similar to the approach I write about above, except slightly simpler with the piping.

Do you know if it's possible to do a recursive args/arga, so you can do:
   
   :cd directory
   :arga * | tab sball

?

Answer (score 5):

Upon browsing the web more extensively, researching in regards to this question, the best solution I've found so far is:

```
:arga file1 file2 file3 (...)
```

Which will create buffers for all the input files.
Then follow that by:

```
:tab sball
```

Which will open all the buffers into separate tabs. 
But maybe there's an even better/shorter way? If not maybe I'm helping someone else out there, having the same problem/question.