# How to use Chrome tab shortcuts in Vim

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm used to using cmd-option + arrows to switch between tabs in Chrome. I'd like to do the same in Vim without having to learn vimscript right way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using MacVim? Or Vim via the terminal?

Comment: I use both but mostly MacVim. I take it cmd wouldn't work in the terminal?

Comment: As an alternative you may want to look into using [buffer's effectively](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21338192/438329)

Comment: Yeah I think you have a point Peter. I've been using Vim for a couple of months now and it's time I start using buffers a lot more. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
:nnoremap <D-A-Down> <C-PageDown>
:nnoremap <D-A-Up> <C-PageUp>
```

should do it.  The `<D->` modifier is Mac-specific.  For other options, see

```
:help keycodes
```

Answer (score 2):

[You can use some alternative mappings](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Alternative_tab_navigation).  The terminal may not play nice with some of these because `<Tab>` is a control key already.

Something like:

```
nnoremap <C-t> :tabe<CR>                                                        
nnoremap <C-tab> :tabn<CR>                                                
nnoremap <C-S-tab> :tabp<CR>
```

This will not necessarily work depending on your terminal and terminal settings, so you would just have to learn to use other navigation keys.