# Is there a way to switch between tabs in vim using `⌘ + ⌥` - `left or right` like Google Chrome or Sublime Text?

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I realize this may be a small thing, but I enjoy being able to quickly switch between current tabs this way.  I'm basically looking for how to put this in my `.vimrc` file. I've edited key bindings plenty for Sublime Text but not for Vim.

I'm using iTerm as the GUI.

Thanks for any davice!

Comment: I suggest using less tab's and learn to [use buffers effectively](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21338192/438329)

Comment: While I agree that it's nice to have one consistent way across apps for switching tabs, I've grown fond of having spacebar remapped to :tabnext. Sounds wacky, but it's fast and convenient. `:noremap <Space> :tabnext<CR>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in CLI Vim because:

- it doesn't understand multiple modifier keys
- it doesn't understand the <kbd>⌘</kbd> key anyway (only MacVim does and only in its GUI incarnation)

But you can create custom shortcuts in iTerm itself that send raw characters to the terminal.

[image: iTerm Preferences]

Anyway, the default `gt` and `gT` are far better, buit-in and guaranteed to work everywhere. What is the most important weapon in your arsenal? Vim or Chrome? Get used to Vim's way or you'll never rip any benefit.

Comment: Well, I didn't get your comment at all.

Comment: Sorry, yeah that wasn't a very good one.  What would I put in my .vimrc file to overwrite anything taking control of those commands?

Comment: Hmm… `gt` and `gT` are built-in commands, those are the ones you should use. If you want to use other mappings instead, you'll have to create your own custom mappings, something like `nnoremap <somekey> gt`. But, like I told you, you won't be able to make Vim understand multiple-modifiers or the `Cmd` key so you'll have to think hard about what keys to use for your mappings. Really, use `gt` and `gT`, read the link posted by benjifisher and *drop that stupid Jarvis distribution.*