# Vim change titlebar to match file in tab

Tags: vim

If I open a file in vim, the titlebar displays the file and path of what I opened. Great. But if I open another tab, and switch to that new tab, the title bar never changes. Even if I completely change files, such as by doing `:edit <newfile>`, the title bar never changes.

I have set the status bar to correctly match the file that is open, however I would like the title bar to do the same. Its confusing sometimes seeing different information displayed at the top and bottom of my window. How can I set the title bar to display the new file that is currently displayed?

Comment: 1) How are you using vim? gvim? macvim? vim in the terminal? 2) Your question makes me think that you are using/abusing tabs. You may want to consider using buffers instead. [Learn to use buffers effectively](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21338192/438329)

Comment: This may have something to do with your terminal emulator: `:set title` should make Vim update your terminal's title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:set titlestring=%F` seems to have fixed it for me. I guess this was a simple one

You can find more info with

```
:help titlestring
```