# gVim switching to the wrong tab

Tags: vim, tabs

I use Vim besides programming for blogging and commenting. The latter leads to a few hundred open textbuffers in tabs in gVim to be able to search for useful text over all comments and copy it into a new comment. I save the whole session when exiting gVim for auto-opening the buffers when restarting it.

Today, with 270 buffers open in 257 tabs, I ran into a weird problem when switching the tabs with the mouse (tabpagemax is set to 1000, but the fact that this error occured around the 256th tab is a bit suspicious - Is there some limiting setting in the GUI I don't know about?). If I'm on tab 255 and click on tab 256 gVim jumps to tab 254 instead of 256. With another click on tab 256 it instantly shows me tab 253, after another click on tab 256 it jumps back to tab 252 and so on.
When clicking on the last tab (257) gVim switches to the very first tab/buffer. If I open another tab Vim does it and navigating with gt and gT trough the additional tabs above tab 255 works fine but clicking on the new tab 258 opens tab 2. So I assume the tab counter of the GUI ends with 256. Is there a way to fix this?

(BTW: Sorry if my English is hard to understand. I'm not a native speaker of English.)

Comment: 257 tabs, oh my! Vim prefers buffers over tabs. You may want to learn to use [buffers effectively](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21338192/438329).

Answer (score 1):

Congrats you found a bug. Read `:h bugs` and report it at vim_dev@vim.org. There is probably no way to fix it without recompiling vim.

---

Why do you have so many tabs? Do you really need tabs you probably could get by with just using the buffers. Read how to [use buffers effectively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21338192/1890567).