# Is it possible to create 2 tab in VIM with separate buffers?

Tags: vim, tabs, buffer

I mostly work on website and sometimes I need to have 3 or 4 buffers displayed for backend and 3 or 4 buffers for frontend at the same time. Tabs are here for that but buffers are mixed. I know I'm a bit fussy but is there a way create buffers "collections" from tab ? It could limit number of opened buffers by tab and be easier to switch from one (buffer) to another.

Comment: personally I feel buffers + splits are much more comfortable (with some plugin, i.e. ctrlp or fussyfinder) than tab... I rarely open files in tab. Maybe I didn't learn the power of tab....

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Using Vim's tabs like buffers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102384/) (along several other questions on the "Related" column on the right)

Comment: I agree with Kent on not using tabs. Here are some tips on how to use [buffers effectively](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21338192/438329) (note this is about closing tabs, but the topic is relevant)

Comment: I agree with you, my question is not really clear. I use buffer and splited windows, but I like to use tabs to make a distinction between buffers, a tab with splited buffers for frontend, another tab with splited windows for backend. Like that I wil not mix up files

Comment: Have you thought about something like separate instances of vim in different tmux windows?

Comment: Yes that could be the solution if nothing else can do that in a single vim instance. To be honest I use gvim on windows so I still open 2 gvim, which is not really convenient.

Answer (score 3):

I use tabs quite extensively to work on different directories (sometimes 4+ tabs)

Combining a plugin like `CtrlP` and the `:lcd` command you can effectively have multiple workspaces (each with a different directory) with minimal mental upkeep.

The `:lcd` command changes the directory for the current window only, so the way I use it is as follows.

1. Open a new tab with `:tabnew`
2. `:lcd ~/somewhere/else`
3. `ctrl + p` (default binding for `CtrlP` to open files in current directory) and find the file you want to edit
4. switch between tabs using `:tn` and `:tp` (obviously I have keybindings for these since I do a lot of switching)

So basically each tab will have it's own working directory, and you use `ctrl + p` to switch between files/buffers.

Comment: Yep it's the same use that I have, but buffers are shared between tabs, and this is what I want to avoid if it's possible

Comment: May I ask why sharing buffers is a concern for you? If you're only opening files using `ctrlP` then you should only be able to access files within that "workspace" right? Are you using `bufdo` extensively? (Sorry I didn't quite answer your original question)

Comment: I use vim with nerdtree to open files and lycosaexplorer to navigate through buffers, and in the same projects I can open many buffers. Split this buffers list with tabs would be more comfortable when I search a specific buffer : I open a tab for js files, a tab for php files, but when I search an opened buffer in my js tab, I see all the php buffers and I don't want to see them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have window-local argument lists:

```
$ vim
:arglocal foo bar baz
:tabnew
:arglocal arthur robert charles
```

Now, `:args` in the first tab page should output:

```
[foo] bar baz
```

and, in the second tab page:

```
[arthur] robert charles
```

One potential problem with this approach is that you are somehow restrained to argument-specific commands:

```
:n[ext]
:prev[ious]  (or :N[ext])
:fir[st]     (or :rew[ind])
:la[st]
:argl[ocal]
```

and tab-specific commands:

```
:tabn[ext]                         (or gt)
:tabp[revious]  (or :tabN[ext])    (or gT)
:tabfir[st]     (or :tabr[ewind])
:tabl[ast]
```

which are not as flexible as the more generic commands available if you only use a global argument list (`:b <tab>`, the cycling nature of `:bn/:bp`…).

That said, you still have the possibility to look for a plugin on vim.org.

Comment: I've tried to open buffer in tabs with :arglocal myfile.ext but buffer are still shared between tabs

Comment: The local argument list is passed over to new windows. Creating a new tab with `:tabnew` and then use `:arglocal` to populate the argument list of the new default window is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using: vim + tmux window / session, for tow frontend and backend dir. else you should use @romainl answer with some limit or create your own plugin.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).