# How to open a terminal in new tab from VIM?

Tags: vim

When I'm working with lets say 4 files, all are open in tabs(VIM). I want to save the changes and compile it without having to close the tabs, i.e I want to open a terminal in new tab along with the existing 4?

How should I do this in VIM?

Comment: This may give an answer or hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102384/using-vims-tabs-like-buffers

Comment: Have you looked into using `:make`? See `:h :make`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Vim 8.1](https://www.vim.org/vim-8.1-released.php) now has a built in terminal that can be opened with the :term command. This provides much more complete integration with the rest of the Vim features.

---

Original Answer:

I would suggest looking at [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). I use tmux myself and along with [vim-tmux-navigator](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator) moving between the terminal and vim is very easy.

Answer (score 32):

```
:tab ter
```

opens a terminal **in a new tab** instead of opening it in a new window as `:ter` does. You can also use the equivalent, longer `:tab terminal` form.

Credits to user wolloda [in this Reddit post](https://libredd.it/r/vim/comments/ait1vz/new_tab_with_only_terminal/).

**Extra information**

- Terminating the shell with `Ctrl-d` or `exit` closes the terminal buffer.
- `Ctrl-w` `N` or `Ctrl-\ Ctrl-n` put the buffer in the terminal-normal mode:
  Keystrokes are not forwarded to the shell, but are used by Vim as in a normal buffer
  (although the shell job is still running). Then you can use `gt` to change tabs,
  type Ex commands such as `:ls`, etc. To bring the terminal buffer back to life,
  `i`, `a`, ...
- If you are going to map this, I recommend using `:tab ter++kill=hup`, so that when you `:qa` the terminal job does not prevent Vim from quitting.
  And this is the signal normal terminal emulators send to its jobs when closed anyway.
- For terminal mode mappings, use `tnoremap`, for example

  ```
  tnoremap <S-Tab> <C-W>:tabprevious<CR>
  tnoremap <C-N>   <C-W>N
  ```

More information on `:help :terminal` and `:help :tab`.

Comment: `nmap <leader><leader> :tab ter<CR>A` <- I added this mapping in my vimrc. When I open terminal using `:tab ter` in neovim, the terminal opens in new tab, but is not ready to take input. For this, I added the `A` at the end of the command (inssert end of line).
Now I just need to press <space> twice (my leader is set to space) to open terminal in new tab.

Answer (score 7):

In 2019, vim now has a Terminal mode.

```
:help terminal
```

For example, you can use it like this.

```
# go to terminal-job mode
:terminal

# go to terminal-normal mode
ctrl-w N

# go back to terminal-job mode
i

# open terminal in new tab
:tab terminal
```

Answer (score 3):

A more vim like way of doing this would be to use `:make`

#### :make

- `:make` will execute the `'makeprg'`. It defaults to `make` which is great of C projects
- After running `:make` the quickfix list will be contain any errors.
- Set your compiler via the `:compiler` command.
- Extra parameter can be passed like so `:make foo-command`
- Current filename can be represented by `%`. e.g. `:make %`

#### quickfix list

- Use `:cnext` and `:cprev` to move between your errors.
- `:copen` to open up the quickfix list in a window (`:cclose` to close)
- `:cwindow` to open quickfix list window only if there are errors
- May want to use better mappings for `:cnext` and friends. I suggest Tim Pope's [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin

#### Alternatives and Plugins

- Just use `<c-z>` to suspend vim and run your build system. (Cons: loose out on the quickfix list)
- Use `:!` to compile. (Same cons as suspending) e.g. `:!make`
- [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) is a syntax checking system that checks files on save
- [Dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) can be used to run things in the background. Great for test suites
- As @brettanomyces mentioned you may want to consider terminal multiplexers like [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).
- [SingleComplile](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3115) tries and takes some of the work out of using `:make`

#### Conclusion

If you are just starting out I would suggest you learn how to use `:make` and the quickfix list. There is a nice [Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/) episode that intros the quickfix list: [Search multiple files with :vimgrep](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/). Additionally Syntastic is a great way to get up and running with linters quickly.

#### Aside about tabs

Vim's tabs are not like most text editors tab. They are more like viewports into a group of windows/splits. Additionally, Vim is buffer centric, not tab centric like most editors. Therefore using features like the quickfix list is often easier without tabs (See `:h 'switchbuf` if you must use tabs). Vim's tabs often get in the way of using a splits as there are better window and buffer navigation commands available. I personally have many files open (sometimes 100+) use no tabs and use on average 1-2 splits without any issue. Bottom line: Learn to [use buffers effectively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21338192/438329).

For more help see the following:

```
:h :make
:h 'makeprg
:h quickfix
:h :cnext
:h :cope
```

Answer (score 1):

### For anyone using *NeoVim*:

The highest voted answer uses `:tab ter`. This doesn't work on NeoVim (at least for me). However, it's still fairly simple:

`:tabe term://bash`

`tabe` is open a new `tab` and `e`dit file.

`term://` is a NeoVim way of opening a terminal

`bash` is the kind of shell you want to use (e.g. I use zsh, so my command is actually `:tabe term://zsh`)

Some helpful commands that I created:

```
" open terminal
if has('nvim')
    command Terminal vsplit term://zsh
    command TerminalTab tabe term://zsh
else
    command Terminal vert term
    command TerminalTab tab ter
endif
```

Comment: thx!  how to do this? open terminal in a new tab, then paste, then go to insert mode, with one line.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is something like this? https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/36586/40187

Answer (score 0):

Another way

Ctrl-w :

That gets me to the command line, then one can enter tablast tabnext or tabprevious

or the short versions tabl, tabn, tabp

Or this way:

Ctrl-w gt  and Ctrl-w gT
(Next tab   and Previous Tab)

Or Ctrl-w Number gt (for a specific tab)

That works too.