# How to open a terminal in new tab in Neovim with only one command without remap?

Tags: vim, neovim

Since 2019, Vim introduces a new command called `:terminal`, which allow user to open terminal inside of Vim.

To open it in a **new tab**, I have to type two commands:

```
:tabnew
```

```
:terminal
```

Is there a one-command way to achieve the same purpose?

Edit: I'm aware of this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411645/how-to-open-a-terminal-in-new-tab-from-vim), but the accepted answer is outdated.

Edit 2: This might be a bug related to Neovim.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is `:tab` command. So one can do `:tab term` and no worries.

Please, when you feel you miss some bit of Vim, don't hesitate to search through builtin help first. In particular, `:h :tabnew` and `:h :tab` topics stay very close to each other, residing within the same help file. As it contains more topics and advices on the subject, you may want to display it by typing `:h tabpage` and read it from the start till the end.

Upd.: If we talk about Neovim specifically (please, note that as long as your question only has "Vim" tag everyone assumes it's NOT Neovim specific), then one should remember that in Neovim `:term` command always reuses the current buffer. Currently this is considered as a feature, not a bug.

Hence for Neovim we may want to have (at least) two commands: one to create a new empty buffer, and another one to re-use it for terminal. How you prefer this, it's fully upon you. `:tabnew | term`, or `:tabnew +term`, or `:tabnew term://sh` and so on.

Comment: `:tab term` does not really open the terminal in a new tab, instead it overrides my current buffer with a terminal.

Comment: @WongJiaHau If you happen to run Neovim, you must mention it in your question directly.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, I just realized `:tab term` does work in Vim but not in Neovim, I've edited the question.

Comment: `:tabnew | term` indeed work in Neovim, just tested