# Vim: How to turn off splitting

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin

Is there a way to permanently turn off window splitting? I want all buffers to open in full windows. Can it be turned off permanently somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Vim's tabs like buffers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102384/using-vims-tabs-like-buffers)

Comment: Yes, don't use splitting commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

- avoid any commands that create window splits
- configure Vim to minimize creation of splits (e.g. `:set switchbuf-=split`),
- additionally define `:autocmd`s that check for created splits and `:tabedit` them instead

but you won't succeed in totally getting rid of them. For example, the *preview* and *quickfix* windows were designed to be viewed in a window split, and you won't get much value out of them without that.

Vim is different than most other editors, and it derives a lot of its power from that. So, try to rid yourself of preconceptions, be open to the *Vim way*, keep experimenting and learning. You'll get by with multiple windows with a few built-in (`<C-w>...`) commands. Maybe you'll only use window splits occasionally, maybe you'll later recognize the shortcomings of alternative approaches of buffer handling (e.g. too many tabs) and start to love window splits. But **don't try to expunge a feature because you initially don't like / understand it**.

Comment: Some additional links related to this subject: [Why do Vim experts prefer buffers over tabs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26708822/438329) and [Use buffers effectively!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21338192/438329)