# Configure Vim/bash to open all files in separate tab when I run vim *

Tags: bash, vim

How can I configure Vim/bash to open all files in separate tab when I run `vim *` (with no other parameters)?

Moreover, can I configure Vim to do a filter of the files given, i.e. I would like to store file extensions that Vim should consider? For example, suppose I have a directory with following files:

```
program1.h
program1.cc
program1.o
program2.cpp
```

I would like Vim open only `.h`, `.cc` and `.cpp` files.

Comment: `vim -p` for the first part.  vim -p *.{h,cc,cpp} for the other.

Comment: @BrianTiffin `vim -p` is apparently opening directories (as a listing), too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer:

```
vim -p *.h *.cc *.cpp
```

As @Brian Tiffin mentioned the `-p` flag opens the files in tabs. The rest is just normal unexciting file globbing.

Note: `-p` will default to opening a max of 10 tab pages.

Personally I would just open up vim without any parameters and just open the files with `:e` as needed. If you really do need a list of files I would pass the files in via globs from the command line or use `:args` to populate the arglist. e.g. `:args *.h *.cc *.cpp`

...What about the no parameter restriction?

You are essentially asking to either white-list or black-list certain filetypes. Such a behavior is both confusing and potentially causes surprises down the road. A related solution is to use `'wildignore'`.

#### Aside about tabs and buffers

It also seems like you are doing a heavily tab centric workflow. I know it might sound weird but maybe use less tab panes and more buffers. Here are some nice posts about it:

- [Why do Vim experts prefer buffers over tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26708822/438329)
- [Use buffers effectively!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21338192/438329)

#### For more help see

```
:h -p
:h :e
:h arglist
:h 'wildignore'
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why don't you want to give other parameters for `vim`?

Still you can do it like (in your `.vimrc`):

```
au BufAdd,BufNewFile * nested tab sball
```

For the second part, you can do it like:

```
au BufAdd,BufNewFile *.o bdelete!
```

Still for this I'd recommend to use something like a `bash` function like parsing the parameter list to the function and rejecting file(mask)s you don't want to edit, and pass the filtered list to `vim` (as the above solution still opens the `*.o` files, which can be slow, etc.)