# Gvim middle click to close tab

Tags: user-interface, vim

In Gvim (GUI Vim), I can open tabs using

`:tabedit https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_tab_pages.`

How do I close a tab by middle clicking on it?

Comment: Doesn't that go against vim's philosophy? Why do you want to touch your mouse to do stuff in (g)vim? You can just press `ZZ` to write and close the current tab or `ZQ` to close it without writing it.

Comment: Also, are you asking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21332096/1281339)? according to which it's `nnoremap <MiddleMouse> :tabclose<CR> `